# "Laravel Error"- Invalid route action: [App\http\Livewire\Logout]

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 8 works fine with laragon locally with the same code, when I upload the same project in the Cpanel and run it shows the error below. I scrutinized the code and could not find the solution. Included the route file below.

The Error:

> Invalid route action: [App\http\Livewire\Logout].

**Web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\http\Livewire\Logout;
use App\http\Livewire\Login;
use App\http\Livewire\Register;   

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('logout', Logout::class)->name('logout');       
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });   

});

Route::group(['middleware'=>'guest'], function(){
    Route::get('login', Login::class)->name('login');        
    Route::get('register', Register::class)->name('register');
});
```

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: You are using both `App/http` and `App/Http` namespace. One of these must be wrong unless you actually have two different folders one named `http` and the other `Http`

Comment: oops! I did not see that. It's Http. Now it works fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @kalecaliber use and IDE so it highlights that stuff, it is basic.

Comment: I have been using Vs code.